# How to put upward arrow with text below the elements of an array

Tags: arrows, arrays

I want to put upward arrow with text below some elements of an array.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12 pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
          a4paper,
          total={170 mm,257 mm},
          left=20 mm,
          top=20 mm,
         }
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

\begin{document}

    \indent \textbf{Step 1 :} \hspace{0.2 cm} Weight the given binary number. \\[0.1 cm]
    \[
    \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
         1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \textbf{.} & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1
    \end{array}
    \]  

\end{document}
```

With the above code I am getting the following output:

[image: Obtained output]

I want the output as follows:

[image: Desired output]

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\substack` and `\textstyle\uparrow`. I suggest using a local macro in order to ease input. The `\hidewidth` bits are to avoid the negative numbers taking up space.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Step 1:}\quad Weight the given binary number.
\[
  \newcommand{\wt}[2]{%
    \underset{\substack{\textstyle\uparrow\\\hidewidth\mathstrut#2\hidewidth}}{#1}%
  }
  \begin{array}{*{11}{c}}
  \wt{1}{5} & \wt{0}{4} & \wt{1}{3} & \wt{1}{2} & \wt{0}{1} & \wt{1}{0} &
  \bm{.} &
  \wt{1}{-1} & \wt{0}{-2} & \wt{1}{-3} & \wt{1}{-4}
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

You can move the definition of `\wt` in the preamble if you need the construct several times.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A solution with TikZ, just for the sake of completeness

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix(mybinary)[matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, row sep=1em,column sep=.5em]{%
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \textbf{.} & 1  & 0  &  1 & 1  \\
 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 &            & -1 & -2 & -3 & -4 \\
};
\foreach\x in {1,2,...,6}{
\draw[<-] (mybinary-1-\x) -- (mybinary-2-\x); 
};
\foreach\x in {8,9,...,11}{
\draw[<-] (mybinary-1-\x) -- (mybinary-2-\x); 
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using the `amsmath` package you can try something like this:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccc}
    $\underset{5}{\stackrel{1}{\uparrow}}$ & $\underset{4}{\stackrel{0}{\uparrow}}$ & $\underset{3}{\stackrel{1}{\uparrow}}$ & $\underset{2}{\stackrel{1}{\uparrow}}$ & $\underset{1}{\stackrel{0}{\uparrow}}$ & $\underset{0}{\stackrel{1}{\uparrow}}$ & \textbf{.} & $\underset{-1}{\stackrel{1}{\uparrow}}$ & $\underset{-2}{\stackrel{0}{\uparrow}}$ & $\underset{-3}{\stackrel{1}{\uparrow}}$ & $\underset{-4}{\stackrel{1}{\uparrow}}$
\end{tabular}
```

Is a little bit messy but you can get somthing like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How do you like

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \textbf{.} & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    \uparrow &\uparrow &\uparrow &\uparrow &\uparrow &\uparrow &&
    \uparrow &\uparrow &\uparrow &\uparrow \\
    5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0&&
    -1&-2&-3&-4
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

which results in

[image]